Nested design with fixed and random effects: Is my R model correct?
I am trying to analyze a nested experimental design in R, but I am unsure whether I am approaching it correctly. I have a following data:



Set
Sample
Repet.
Response




1
1
1
y1


1
1
2
y2


1
2
1
y3


1
2
2
y4


1
3
1
y5


1
3
2
y6


1
4
1
y7


1
4
2
y8


2
1
1
y9


2
1
2
y10


2
2
1
y11


2
2
2
y12


... (data continues) ...






In my dataset, 'Set' is a fixed effect I control in the experiment. 'Sample' represents nested levels within each 'Set', and 'Repet.' are repetitions nested within each 'Sample'.
My goal is to determine whether variance arises from Sample within Set or from Repet. within Sample. I believe this is a nested design.
I have attempted to approach this using R, but I am unsure if my code or statistical approach is correct. Here's my attempt using the lme4 package:
library(lme4)
modelSS <- lmer(Response ~ Set + (1|Set:Sample) + 
      (1|Set:Sample:Repet.), data = data)
summary(modelSS)

My questions are:
Is this a correct way to analyze variance in nested designs?
How can I evaluate which level contributes the most to variance?
Is lme4 good package for this or should I try mixlm (and if so, how the code would be written in that case)

See if this helps: https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#model-definition . It will also be helpful here if you explain a bit more about the design. Are the y’s from people at different times? Also, make sure to decide if set is both fixed and random or just fixed. You currently have it specified as both

Could you include a (link to) the complete data?
